# How do I Order By on multiple rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, sorting

I have a table with columns with severities like:

```
name   | critical | major | trivial 
----------------------------------------
Apache |2         |3      |2
Eclipse|5         |0      |4
TestNg |0         |0      |5
JUnit  |0         |2      |7
```

I want to list the rows in the order by their severities in descending order - critical, major and trivial.

For the above example, I'd like to get back:

```
name  | critical | major | trivial 
----------------------------------------
Eclipse|5         |0      |4
Apache |2         |3      |2
JUnit  |0         |2      |7
TestNg |0         |0      |5
```

critical has highest severity, then comes major and then trivial. Notice eclipse has to come first since 5 > 2 (Critical, internal sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply order them  with the right orde4r with `DESC` for descending

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  "name" VARCHAR(7),
  "critical" INTEGER,
  "major" INTEGER,
  "trivial" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test
  ("name", "critical", "major", "trivial")
VALUES
  ('Apache', '2', '3', '2'),
  ('Eclipse', '5', '0', '4'),
  ('TestNg', '0', '0', '5'),
  ('JUnit', '0', '2', '7');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY "critical" DESC, "major" DESC, "trivial" DESC;

| name    | critical | major | trivial |
| ------- | -------- | ----- | ------- |
| Eclipse | 5        | 0     | 4       |
| Apache  | 2        | 3     | 2       |
| JUnit   | 0        | 2     | 7       |
| TestNg  | 0        | 0     | 5       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/11)

Comment: Thank you! I somehow thought it was way more complicated